# How to validate requests with FluentValdation instead of data annotations?

Tags: c#, .net-5, fluentvalidation

I created a new .Net 5 Web API with the following setup

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{Title}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get([FromRoute] RouteModel routeModel)
    {
        return Ok(routeModel);
    }
}

public class RouteModel
{
    [MinLength(3)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

The request validation works fine. Since I'm using FluentValidation I installed the package

> FluentValidation.AspNetCore v10.3.0

and updated the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method to

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebApplication", Version = "v1" });
    });
}
```

Instead of using the data annotations I removed the data annotations from `RouteModel.Title` and created this validator

```
public class RouteModelValidator : AbstractValidator<RouteModel>
{
    public RouteModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(model => model.Title).MinimumLength(3);
    }
}
```

I would expect a `ValidationException` and this would result into a 500 status code if the title has a length less than 3. But it seems there is no validation trigger anymore, the request always passes.

Does someone know what's missing?

Comment: Could you share all the code from the ConfigureServices method that relates to the FluentValidation registration?

Comment: please try it: `services.AddFluentValidation(x => x.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()));`

Comment: I added the line, unfortunately that didn't help

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, since I write `services.AddFluentValidation`

Comment: You can see the 3 files here https://pastebin.com/KVPwtWjm When I send a request with `title = "a"` I would expect an exception. Do you get an exception with that code?

Comment: could you please try to add `[ApiController]` to your controller? @Question3r

Comment: ah, that fixed it :) If you want you can create an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Register FluentValidation as

   ```
   services
     .AddFluentValidation(x => x.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()));
   ```
2. Mark your Controller with `ApiController` attribute

   ```
   [ApiController]
   public class MyController : ControllerBase
   ```

Otherwise, you should manually validate `ModelState`, something like:

```
[HttpGet("{Title}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get([FromRoute] RouteModel routeModel)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return BadRequest("bad");
   }
   return Ok(routeModel);
}
```

[Some info:](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1812)

> It depends on the type of controller - if you're using the [ApiController] attribute, then ASP.NET will generate a Bad Request result automatically. If you don't use the ApiController attribute (ie for non-api controllers, such as where you return a view), then you're expected to handle the ModelState.IsValid check manually (see the asp.net doc link above). But again, this is a convention of ASP.NET, it isn't a feature of FluentValidation.